# Extjs - (double) creating a second popup on top of another popup breaks hide/show functionality?

Tags: extjs, popup

**Ext version tested: 6.2.1 rev 167**

**Browser versions tested against: Chrome  112.0.5615.165 Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS**

**Description:**
two popups with animation not working when a second popup is created a double creation is triggered

1.open first popup by clicking on the settings button;
2a. open second popup by focusing the text field;
3. pressing cancel button hides the second popup

2b. if double clicked on the text field instead (on first load - not created yet)- cancel button doesn't work

**Fiddle**
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3olu

removing one of the popups seems to help
alternatively - removing the animation seems to help to certain degree(depending on the Ext version)

Answer (score 0):

this happens because when double-clicking the textbox focus event is  called twice and also executing show() twice too breaking the popup, a solution is to disable the textbox the first time if focus it and enable again when closing the popup:

on focus on the textbox put this.disable();

```
       listeners:{
           focus: function(){
             
             this.disable();

             let cSelectPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#cSelectPanel')[0];
             
             if (typeof cSelectPanel == "undefined") {
                cSelectPanel = Ext.create('cSelectPanel');
                Ext.Viewport.add(cSelectPanel);
             }
             cSelectPanel.show();
             
           },
          
       }
```

and on hide on the popup panel re-enable:

```
  listeners:{
        hide: function(){
               
               var txt = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#MyText')[0];
               txt.enable();
               
           }
   },
```

Hope that helps